# Decrypting a cookie in .NET 6 fails with "The payload was invalid."

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, cookies

With our NET 6.0 web app, I'm trying to decrypt a cookie and display the contents to my logger/logging-sink.

I keep getting the following error:

> The payload was invalid

I have a few cookies in the cookie jar/browser. The one in particular is the `.AspNetCore.Cookies` cookie.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Cookies"];
var content = DecryptCookie(_dataProtectionProvider, cookie.Key, cookie.Value); 
logger.LogInformation(content);


private static string DecryptCookie(IDataProtectionProvider provider, string cookieKey, string cookieValue)
{
    var dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", cookieKey, "v2");

    // Get the decrypted cookie as plain text.
    UTF8Encoding specialUtf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true);
    byte[] protectedBytes = Base64UrlTextEncoder.Decode(cookieValue);
    byte[] plainBytes = dataProtector.Unprotect(protectedBytes);
    string plainText = specialUtf8Encoding.GetString(plainBytes);

    // Get the decrypted cookie as a Authentication Ticket.
    TicketDataFormat ticketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);
    AuthenticationTicket ticket = ticketDataFormat.Unprotect(cookieValue);

    return "This is working!!!"; // Yes, I know. This will be the plainText? Not sure just yet.
}
```

But it keeps dying here:

[image]

More Info:

As to the setup of the `DataProtectionProvider`? <strike>I'm not sure? this is localhost development (I just hit F5) so I'm not sure if it's just InMemory or if it might be using Redis (I think someone said in production they use Redis for it .. for 'reasons'. I think it's sharing the cookies or something? I'm not too sure).</strike> It's a Redis XML Store (implements `IXmlRepository`). Not sure if that means anything, here.

Can anyone please help why this isn't working?

#### EDIT 1:

Another suggestion from elsewhere was this:

```
private static string DecryptCookie(IDataProtectionProvider provider, string cookieKey, string cookieValue)
{
    var dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", cookieKey, "v2");

    return dataProtector.Unprotect(cookieValue);
}
```

This too, returns the same exception/error message.

It's like I'm failing to generate a valid/correct `CreateProtector` ?

Answer (score 0):

There were 2x tricks

1 - Need to use the same values the auth ticket was "Protected" with

- `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware"`
- `"Cookies"`

2 - Need to convert to the cookie value to an `AuthenticationTicket` before we try and unprotect it.

```
    private static string DecryptCookie(IDataProtectionProvider provider, string cookieKey, string cookieValue)
    {  
        // Data protector has to be the same one used when the cookie is Protected.
        var dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector(
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
            "Cookies",
            "v2");
    
        // The cookie data is in the form of a 'Ticket Data'. So we unprotect it, to that.
        var ticketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);
        var ticket = ticketDataFormat.Unprotect(cookieValue, "");
    
        // Lets get -some- data from the cookie.
        // The 'Principal' is more or less, unable to be serialized.
        var cookieProperties = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ticket.Properties);
    
        return cookieProperties; // FOR EXAMPLE.
    }
```